Running auto test on selected contr and aggent from yaml files in azure pipelines
We can run tests either locally (launched from our own machine), or using a Test Controller which farms out the tests to multiple Test Agents so they can be run in parallel.
so we are planning to use 2nd option which using test controller to run tests from azure pipelines.
If We use the Multiple Agents test settings file, our tests will be run through the Test Controller. Since we choose this option, We will need to put a ConfigClient.endpoint.config file in
Pp\bin, which is from azure repo. Here is the screenshot of ConfigClient.endpoint.config file
and this ConfigClient.endpoint.config file which points to the config service in the environment we want to test. This file will get copied down to the Test Agents and that is how each Test Agent will know which environment to run against.
can we select/parameterize the environment we give in the build for above location, if yes how?
Since we have large amount of automations tests to run we can use a Test Controller which farms out the tests to multiple Test Agents so they can be run in parallel.
Currently we have
Controller : ConrollerServer.Domain.local
Agents : Controllerserver.Domain.local through server.domain.local
so we have 12 agents
here in the code we choose controller below highlighted, can we select/parameterize controller ? if yes how?
I heared that it can be done using replace token, but how to achieve that, can you please example.
1.I have tried to use parameter but it did not work
2. I have tried to use replace token but not sure how to amend that task and get the desired results
3. I tried to  use variables along with parameter but it did not work

It's right that you can use the Replace Tokens task to pass a selected Controller into the testsettings file:

The testsettings file, you can set like as below. The {{ TestSettings_Name }} and {{ RemoteController_Name }} are the placeholder tokens that will be replaced with the actual selected values by the Replace Tokens task.

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<TestSettings name="{{ TestSettings_Name }}" id="32wfwerfsdr34rtt" xmlns="http://microsoft.com/schemas/visualstudio/xxx">
  <Description>My tests.</Description>
  <RemoteController name="{{ RemoteController_Name }}" />
  <Execution location="Remote">
    <Timeouts runTimeout="27000000" testTimeout="10740000" />
    . . .
  </Execution>
  . . .
</TestSettings>


You can use parameters to dynamically select the Controller when triggering the pipeline.

parameters:
- name: TestSetting
  default: testSet01
  values:
  - testSet01
  - testSet02
  - testSet03
- name: Controller
  default: controller01
  values:
  - controller01
  - controller02
  - controller03


You can use logging command "SetVariable" to set the selected values as pipeline variables so that Replace Tokens task can recognize the values. Ensure to set the name of the variables to be same as that of the placeholder tokens in the testsettings file.

echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=TestSettings_Name;]${{ parameters.TestSetting }}"
echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=RemoteController_Name;]${{ parameters.Controller }}"


A sample of the pipeline YAML.

parameters:
- name: TestSetting
  default: testSet01
  values:
  - testSet01
  - testSet02
  - testSet03
- name: Controller
  default: controller01
  values:
  - controller01
  - controller02
  - controller03


stages:
- stage: A
  jobs:
  - job: A1
    steps:
    - task: Bash@3
      displayName: 'Set variable'
      inputs:
        targetType: inline
        script: |
          echo 'The selected TestSetting is ${{ parameters.TestSetting }}.'
          echo 'The selected Controller is ${{ parameters.Controller }}.'
          echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=TestSettings_Name;]${{ parameters.TestSetting }}"
          echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=RemoteController_Name;]${{ parameters.Controller }}"
    
    - task: Bash@3
      displayName: 'Print file before replace'
      inputs:
        targetType: inline
        script: cat relative/path/to/Azure_Dev.testsettings
    
    - task: replacetokens@6
      inputs:
        root: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)'
        sources: 'relative/path/to/Azure_Dev.testsettings'
        tokenPattern: 'doublebraces'
        missingVarAction: 'keep'
        missingVarLog: 'error'
    
    - task: Bash@3
      displayName: 'Print file after replace'
      inputs:
        targetType: inline
        script: cat relative/path/to/Azure_Dev.testsettings

Results:





Hi Bright.
Thank you for the response.
In first screenshot i shared, there is config end point , where I need to select the target environment. how can we do that? could you please suggest with screenshot example
or above parameters will take care of that environment? and agents?

@user25518631, Yes, you also can use parameters to select and pass the target environment into the pipeline for use. If you also want to pass the value of target environment into the config files, you can use the same method like as my above answer.

HI Bright Okay, suppose this config end point file only available in bin folder in the agent ( VMSS scaleset agent -selfhosted) only while running the pipeline, in that case how to use this replace token method, could you please guide me on this...

@user25518631, Do you mean the config end point file is generated by a step in the pipeline job, not an existing file in the source repository? If so, I am afraid that it is not possible to use the replace token task update the file. Because before using the replace token task, as mentioned above, you need to set the placeholder tokens in the files.

Hi Bright, here I use batch script task  to create file in the agent directory and then as next step I will use replace token task , will it not work?

@user25518631, As I stated previously, to use the replace token task, you first need to set the placeholder tokens in the target file. If the file you created using the batch script does not set the placeholder tokens, the replace token task will not recognize valid any tokens to relace in the file. Normally, the  target file should be an existing file stored in the source repository so that you can manually edit it and set the placeholder tokens in the file.

@user25518631, If the config end point file has the stable and common format, you can consider put a template file in the source repository. For the properties that need to set different values based on the different environments, you can set their values as placeholder tokens in the template file. Then you can reference the steps in my above answer to pass the actual values you select into the template file to replace the placeholder tokens. Ans then you can use the updated file in the subsequent test task.

HI Bright Ran , I see following error when i ran the pipeline with above tasks, task it gave error is set variable task   and error is Unable to locate executable file: 'bash'. Please verify either the file path exists or the file can be found within a directory specified by the PATH environment variable. Also verify the file has a valid extension for an executable file  and fyi:  git already there in the agent . which virtual machine scaleset , Please suggest

HI Bright,, I have tried to add the above tasks but coming up with following error ##[error]Unable to locate executable file: 'bash'. Please verify either the file path exists or the file can be found within a directory specified by the PATH environment variable. Also verify the file has a valid extension for an executable file.     I have tried to add powershell task which installs git and will add envirounment variable as below but still same error,

and other question, since bash task is giving error related to env var. path , can we use any other type of task to work on these replace token assignment?
